# Given 3 nodes in a BST, check if one is ancestor of another and third one is descendant- why does this take O(h) time?

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I am solving a problem where we are given a `BST` and `three nodes`, and we want to determine: "whether
`nodeOne` or `nodeThree` is an ancestor of `nodeTwo`, and the other node is a descendant of nodeTwo."

e.g. if `nodeOne` is ancestor of `nodeTwo`, then check if `nodeThree` is descendant of `nodeTwo`.
Otherwise if `nodeThree` is an ancestor of `nodeTwo`, then check if `nodeOne` is descendant of `nodeTwo`.

It is quite a simple few checks, and we will simply search the BST checking the above, i.e. first if nodeOne is ancestor of nodeTwo, and if not then check if nodeThree is ancestor of nodeTwo, then whichever is True, we will check if the other node is a descendant of nodeTwo.

In my mind, this would take `O(log(n)) time`, where n is number of nodes from fist to last node (first and last are one of the three nodes)- since we know the values of the three nodes, we can eliminate half of the tree each time we traverse down the BST, however in the solution it says that it takes `O(h) time`, where **h is the height of the tree**.

Can someone please clarify why it is indeed `O(h)` time?

I omitted the algorithm as I didnt think it was necessary, but it essentially uses recursion to traverse the tree starting from nodeOne then nodeThree, if nodeOne isn't a descendant of nodeTwo.

Comment: Your question is not about any specific property of Python, nor it discusses any code in that language, so I think the [python] tag is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the tree is a length of the longest path from the tree's root to a leaf. A search in a BST descends along some path from the root node towards a leaf.

That makes no more steps than a number of nodes on a seek path, which in turn is no more than the tree's height – hence O(*h*).

**ADDED:**

You can also find the answer in one pass only. Just seek for `nodeThree` and record if you encounter `nodeOne` and `nodeTwo` along the path.

- If so, and in this order, you're done with a positive answer.
- If you found only one of them, or both but in wrong order, the answer is negative.
- Otherwise, continue seeking from `nodeThree`, this time aiming at `nodeOne`.

  - If you enounter `nodeTwo` before finding `nodeOne` the result is positive.
  - Otherwise, that is you do not find `nodeOne`, or find it without preceding `nodeTwo`, the result is negative.

Comment: Having asked some others, I believe it depends on whether the tree is completely balanced too right? Or skewed. In the case of a skewed BST it would be O(h), and if the tree is balanced and complete  it would be O(log(N)), which incidentally is equal to O(h)?

Comment: @Patrick_Chong No, it does not depend on the tree's shape. You just need to perform two seeks in a tree. Each seek makes at most _h_ steps, so the whole routine needs no more than 2_h_ steps, hence it's O(h). Neither a number of nodes in the tree nor a balance factor appears in the reasoning or in the final result.

Comment: @Patrick_Chong Please see the expanded answer.